# Need a brilliant idea for moving onCreateViewHolder() decision making into the ViewHolders themselves

Tags: android, inheritance, kotlin, android-recyclerview, maintainability

Currently for multi-ViewHolder implementations of RecyclerView everyone suggests to have a `when/switch case` in `onCreateViewHolder()`

e.g. here: [How to create RecyclerView with multiple view type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type)

or here: https://medium.com/@gilbertchristopher/a-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-22619a5ad365

I'd like to have a cleaner `onCreateViewHolder()` method but need a way to move this decision making code into `ViewHolders` themselves.

Any ideas?

Here's my adapter class for more detail in github, I'm currently doing the decision making in `baseViewHolder` Class : https://github.com/davida5/DavidsResume/blob/master/app/src/main/java/davids/resume/screens/resume/ResumeAdapter.kt

Comment: an argument could be made that why `abstract class SectionViewHolder` should know about its children. `ViewHolder`'s job is to bind the data to the view. Cleaner implementation would be to make a generic adapter that exposes abstract functions and the child adapter would override it and provide different implementations. Example: [generic](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kickstarter/ui/adapters/KSAdapter.java), [implementation](https://github.com/kickstarter/android-oss/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kickstarter/ui/adapters/RewardCardAdapter.kt)

Comment: Kickstarter project seems exactly what I need, but It's very complex, I'm still trying to understand how the view is created...

Comment: use [Epoxy](https://github.com/airbnb/epoxy) to deal with recyclerview multiple view types